# Indirect binding to child collections in XAML

Tags: data-binding, xaml, collections, subsonic3, master-detail

I am currently using a Linq template with SubSonic3 to create my models. I have a simple Member class, which has a collection of Notes. A Note class has a PublishedDate and Title properties.

I have a UserControl which has a collection of Members for its `DataContext`. There are two `ListBoxes` and a bunch of `TextBoxes` and other controls on it. The first `ListBox` (membersList) gets its `ItemsSource` from the `UserControl` DataContext and it displays a few Member properties in each item. I would like the second `ListBox` (notesList) to display the Notes collection of the Member selected in the first `ListBox`.

So far on notesList I have:

```
<ListBox ... ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}"...>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

It partially works. When I selected a Member which has Note items there is the correct number of items in `notesListBox` but this is only visible in the alternating row colours - nothing else! The `DataTemplate` fails to render the Title of the Note. Basically all the visual styles in the `ListBox` and `ListBoxItem` works - alternating colours, selection border, mouseover, etc. but the content is not shown. I have a feeling the problem is my Binding syntax but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Dany.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your template includes a [ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx).  It sounds like you may have left this out when you templated your list box.

Leaving this out could lead to the behavior you're experiencing - full template, but no "content", since there's no place for it to place the actual items that should go in each list box item.

Comment: Hi Reed, thanks for the quick response. Yes, I already have a ContentPresenter in the control template. The ControlTemplates are identical for membersList and notesList - the only difference is the DataTemplates. The membersList ListBox is displaying quite nicely, the only problematic one is notesListBox.